Issue with the DEB part of yml file. (Top-level object must be a mapping)
I am unable to use the DEB function from an yml file. is there a way I can resolve this? There was another error earlier that I have ignored since I thought that it wouldn't really be used. I had to setup my ngrok tunnel on my LINUX server using this command;
curl -s https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com/ngrok.asc \
    | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ngrok.asc >/dev/null \
    && echo "deb https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com buster main" \
    | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ngrok.list \
    && sudo apt update \
    && sudo apt install ngrok

The error in question was:

'E: The update command takes no arguments

root ➜ /workspaces/NodeHosting/pterodactyl/wings (main) $

The error that follow through when I tried to use docker-compose up -d --force-recreate was:

Top-level object must be a mapping  the "docker-compose.yml"

file contains only (I think it's because the first thing I had to do didn't work as planned.):
deb https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com buster main docker-compose.yml

I am unsure what else to do.
